# vector vs unique_ptr to c style function

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

When I am interacting with a c-style function which style should I use.

I do plan on storing the data in a vector after it comes back from the c function. What are advantageous of one over the other?

```
{
  auto test = std::make_unique<double[]>(10);
  fooCstyle(test);
}
```

or

```
{
  auto test = std::vector<double>;
  test.reserve(10);
  fooCstyle(test);
}
```

Comment: What's the signature and semantics of the function you want to call?

Comment: fooCstyle(double array[], size_t sizeOfArray);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it makes no difference, it depends on what you want to do with that data later in cpp-styled code.

However your examples are wrong, it should look like this:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(10);
cstyle(buffer.data());
```

or

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> test { new char[10] };
cstyle(test.get());
```

Comment: Are there any performance differences between the two?

Thanks for the correct syntax for the example.

Comment: Unique pointer will be faster as it ships with way less features, it's almost normal pointer.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek `std::make_unique<double[]>(10)` is fine (actually preferable). `unique_ptr` is no faster than `std::vector` In some cases the vector can be faster (short vector optimisation).

Comment: Some implementations lack make_unique and vector operator[] is pretty slow while checking boundaries.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek make_unique is c++14 and beyond. The op used it so he's clearly running with the cool kids. vector boundary checks are not a factor here. The occur only in `std::vector::at` and in debug code (where performance is irrelevant)